# Hibernate - Dialect configured but still getting error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jhipster, hikaricp

I'm updating a JHipster microservice and found some issues when running the app in production environment. The application crashes with a strange Hibernate error:

```
2020-10-22 10:59:12.755  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] [172.18.0.3]:5701 is STARTED
2020-10-22 10:59:13.066 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Driver class org.postgresql.Driver found in Thread context class loader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4ae3c1cd
2020-10-22 10:59:13.868  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1603364353868, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2020-10-22 10:59:13.946  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MISCELLANEOUS/miscellaneous:2b1983b040c376288a15e1a536a4f8f9: registering service...
2020-10-22 10:59:14.182  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MISCELLANEOUS/miscellaneous:2b1983b040c376288a15e1a536a4f8f9 - registration status: 204
2020-10-22 10:59:14.257  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.h.e.m.config.WebConfigurer             : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
2020-10-22 10:59:14.258  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.h.e.m.config.WebConfigurer             : Web application fully configured
2020-10-22 10:59:14.961 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Hikari - configuration:
2020-10-22 10:59:14.969 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2020-10-22 10:59:14.969 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................false
2020-10-22 10:59:14.969 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2020-10-22 10:59:14.970 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2020-10-22 10:59:14.970 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2020-10-22 10:59:14.971 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2020-10-22 10:59:14.971 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2020-10-22 10:59:14.971 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2020-10-22 10:59:14.972 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.042 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2020-10-22 10:59:15.043 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
2020-10-22 10:59:15.043 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName......none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.044 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2020-10-22 10:59:15.045 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.045 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2020-10-22 10:59:15.047 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2020-10-22 10:59:15.048 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2020-10-22 10:59:15.049 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/miscellaneous?socketTimeout=30
2020-10-22 10:59:15.050 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........15000
2020-10-22 10:59:15.050 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2020-10-22 10:59:15.050 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................5
2020-10-22 10:59:15.051 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.051 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.051 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................5
2020-10-22 10:59:15.054 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2020-10-22 10:59:15.055 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"Hikari"
2020-10-22 10:59:15.056 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2020-10-22 10:59:15.057 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2020-10-22 10:59:15.059 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.059 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2020-10-22 10:59:15.059 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2020-10-22 10:59:15.060 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2020-10-22 10:59:15.061 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"teste"
2020-10-22 10:59:15.064 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2020-10-22 10:59:15.065  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Starting...
2020-10-22 10:59:15.445 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@47d6a31a
2020-10-22 10:59:15.450  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Start completed.
2020-10-22 10:59:15.550 DEBUG 1 --- [ari housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Pool stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)
2020-10-22 10:59:15.566 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@c2d5356
2020-10-22 10:59:15.573 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2eaaca3
2020-10-22 10:59:15.643 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6d53826
2020-10-22 10:59:15.654 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@43d7a698
2020-10-22 10:59:15.659 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - After adding stats (total=5, active=1, idle=4, waiting=0)
2020-10-22 10:59:28.156  WARN 1 --- [scoveryClient-0] c.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask  : task supervisor timed out

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask.run(TimedSupervisorTask.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2020-10-22 10:59:30.453  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-22 10:59:30.454 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Before shutdown stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.465 DEBUG 1 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : Hikari - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@47d6a31a: (connection evicted)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.471 DEBUG 1 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : Hikari - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@c2d5356: (connection evicted)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.544 DEBUG 1 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : Hikari - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2eaaca3: (connection evicted)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.545 DEBUG 1 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : Hikari - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6d53826: (connection evicted)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.548 DEBUG 1 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : Hikari - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@43d7a698: (connection evicted)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.564 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
2020-10-22 10:59:30.564  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Shutdown completed.
2020-10-22 10:59:30.565  WARN 1 --- [           main] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Warning, Liquibase took more than 5 seconds to start up!
2020-10-22 10:59:31.050 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        persistence provider classname: null
        classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4ae3c1cd
        excludeUnlistedClasses: true
        JTA datasource: null
        Non JTA datasource: HikariDataSource (Hikari)
        Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
        PU root URL: file:/app/libs/commons-microservice-1.1.0.jar
        Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
        Validation Mode: AUTO
        Jar files URLs []
        Managed classes names [
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.AbstractAuditingEntity
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.Banner
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.CustomPage
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.DirectMail
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.PersistentAuditEvent
                tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.domain.Theme
                tech.h2r.commons.microservice.domain.ConsumedMessage
                tech.h2r.commons.microservice.domain.ProducedMessage
                tech.h2r.commons.domain.Config]
        Mapping files names []
        Properties []
2020-10-22 10:59:31.064 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl     : Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
2020-10-22 10:59:31.066 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl     : Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
2020-10-22 10:59:31.068 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.i.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl     : Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
2020-10-22 10:59:31.270  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-10-22 10:59:31.343 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-10-22 10:59:31.851 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceBinding   : Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]
2020-10-22 10:59:31.867 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : Cannot default RegionFactory based on registered strategies as `[]` RegionFactory strategies were registered
2020-10-22 10:59:31.868 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory
2020-10-22 10:59:31.960  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-10-22 10:59:32.769 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl   : Injecting JPA temp ClassLoader [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@20852557] into BootstrapContext; was [null]
2020-10-22 10:59:32.770 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl  : ClassLoaderAccessImpl#injectTempClassLoader(org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@20852557) [was null]
2020-10-22 10:59:32.771 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl   : Injecting ScanEnvironment [org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.StandardJpaScanEnvironmentImpl@41ca7df9] into BootstrapContext; was [null]
2020-10-22 10:59:32.842 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl   : Injecting ScanOptions [org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions@4f0908de] into BootstrapContext; was [org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions@19469022]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.153 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.BootstrapContextImpl   : Injecting JPA temp ClassLoader [null] into BootstrapContext; was [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@20852557]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.160 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl  : ClassLoaderAccessImpl#injectTempClassLoader(null) [was org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@20852557]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.243 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid2] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.243 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [guid] -> [org.hibernate.id.GUIDGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.244 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.245 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [uuid.hex] -> [org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.245 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [assigned] -> [org.hibernate.id.Assigned]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.247 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.249 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [select] -> [org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.251 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.253 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [seqhilo] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.254 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [increment] -> [org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.255 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [foreign] -> [org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.256 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence-identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.256 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.258 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] .i.f.i.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory : Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.262  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (Hikari) has been closed.
2020-10-22 10:59:33.266  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [tech/h2r/ecommerce/miscellaneous/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-10-22 10:59:33.365  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] [172.18.0.3]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2020-10-22 10:59:33.449  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Shutting down connection manager...
2020-10-22 10:59:33.457  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Shutting down node engine...
2020-10-22 10:59:33.547  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.NodeExtension     : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Destroying node NodeExtension.
2020-10-22 10:59:33.548  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] Hazelcast Shutdown is completed in 101 ms.
2020-10-22 10:59:33.549  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [172.18.0.3]:5701 [dev] [3.12.7] [172.18.0.3]:5701 is SHUTDOWN
2020-10-22 10:59:33.550  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.h.e.m.config.CacheConfiguration        : Closing Cache Manager
2020-10-22 10:59:33.554  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2020-10-22 10:59:36.557  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2020-10-22 10:59:36.666  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MISCELLANEOUS/miscellaneous:2b1983b040c376288a15e1a536a4f8f9 - deregister  status: 200
2020-10-22 10:59:36.744  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2020-10-22 10:59:36.951 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [tech/h2r/ecommerce/miscellaneous/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at tech.h2r.ecommerce.miscellaneous.MiscellaneousApp.main(MiscellaneousApp.java:44)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

The error says the problem is with dialect, but it is configured correctly:

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/miscellaneous?socketTimeout=30
    hikari:
        poolName: Hikari
        auto-commit: false
jpa:
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL10Dialect
    show-sql: false
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
        hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 25
        hibernate.order_inserts: true
        hibernate.order_updates: true
        hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch: true
        hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding: true
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
        hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: miscellaneous
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
            physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
            implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Does it work when you use standard dialect? database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

Comment: @GaëlMarziou didn't try yet. But it is working in mirrored development environment.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use the injected jpaVendorAdapter in my EntityManager, I was creating it:

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider schemaPerTenantConnectionProvider, HeaderTenantIdentifierResolver headerTenantIdentifierResolver) {
    ...
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}
```

simply using the injected bean solved this problem:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider schemaPerTenantConnectionProvider, HeaderTenantIdentifierResolver headerTenantIdentifierResolver, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    ...
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dialect to the properties under the name `hibernate.dialect`.